How can I create a smooth scroll effect for anchor links with JavaScript?
Smooth Scroll Only Works Once:
The first anchor link works fine, but after that, subsequent links cause the page to jump instead of scrolling smoothly.
I’m trying to implement smooth scrolling on my webpage so that when a user clicks on an anchor link, the page scrolls smoothly to the target section instead of jumping instantly

Elaborate your question, attach code snippets and screenshots of the current and required behaviour. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Maybe you don't need JS there is already a ready-made CSS solution
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Smooth Scroll</title>
    <style>
        section {
            height: 100vh;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#section1">Go to Section 1</a>
        <a href="#section2">Go to Section 2</a>
        <a href="#section3">Go to Section 3</a>
    </nav>

    <section id="section1">Section 1</section>
    <section id="section2">Section 2</section>
    <section id="section3">Section 3</section>

    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
            anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const targetId = this.getAttribute('href');
                const targetElement = document.querySelector(targetId);
                targetElement.scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                    block: 'start' // Optional: scrolls to the start of the element
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

